# Why does scale return NaN for zero variance columns?

Tags: r

Consider the following matrix:

```
x <- matrix(c(1,1,1,3),2)
x
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    3
```

When calling `scale` with this, `NaN` values are returned for the first column, which has zero variance:

```
scale(x)
     [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  NaN -0.7071068
[2,]  NaN  0.7071068
attr(,"scaled:center")
[1] 1 2
attr(,"scaled:scale")
[1] 0.000000 1.414214
```

However, I would expect it to return `0`. Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding what this is and should return?

The work around for what I want is:

```
y <- scale(x)
y[is.nan(y)] <- 0
```

But this involves the use of an extra variable, is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: It is 0 / 0 which produces NaN.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because `scale` divides by the variance, it must do this.

Continuous variables really aren't supposed have ties, much less zero variance, and it is not appropriate to scale a discrete or categorical variable.

Comment: +1 Just as a note, `scale` divides by the standard deviation, but obviously the result is the same here.

Comment: Ah, the devil is in the details. I had assumed from the signature in the help file that the `scale` parameter was either `TRUE` or `FALSE`. I think I want to specify my own column scaling here. Thanks

Comment: (+1) I think the question as well is regarding the possibility of removing the extra variable.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the following workaround:

```
apply(x, 2, function(y) (y - mean(y)) / sd(y) ^ as.logical(sd(y)))

     [,1]       [,2]
[1,]    0 -0.7071068
[2,]    0  0.7071068
```

Comment: (+1) as long as the intended usage of `scale` is with both the default arguments `center` and `scale` set to `TRUE`

Comment: Thanks, that's a good workaround. I'll need to reconsider what an appropriate scaling factor is for my application though.